# jsp - Update data without refresh the page using jquery and ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am using jsp with script tag `(<% %>)` .And I use ajax to update some contend of jsp which have Java code with in script. In the script tag I get some session variable to process. And in ajax call I update that session variable from  the action class but I can't get updated value for the front end jsp variable(inside the script tag).

Can any one tell me how do I do this?

Comment: post your code so we can understand more !!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use javascript to update some Java variables which, fortunately or unfortunately, have already been processed by your application server and are no longer present on your output HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up server side and client side programming. JSP code is executed at server side and a your session data will remain at server only. All the output generated from server will be sent to browser and displayed. Although you make a ajax call, the session data will only update at server side but not update at browser unless your ajax call can handle the result from server and update the content accordingly.

Comment: You mean, I have to refresh the page to get updated session variable value for the front end?

Comment: It depends. Since you are updating the session data by Ajax, I think you don't want to refresh the page, right? otherwise, you won't use Ajax. By using Ajax call, your Ajax call should handle the returned result and update the page accordingly.

Comment: Yeah! but problem is how to update the page (which have script tag) according to Ajax call result?

Comment: Your question is about how to update page using ajax instead of jsp, right? Then you should show your code what problems you have to update the page.